# How to make FxCopAnalyzers skip Specflow AssemblyHooks warning

Tags: c#, .net-core, specflow, code-analysis

In my .NET Core 3.1 project, I have Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers 2.9.6 package installed.

There is a warning CA1707 and CA1052 regarding an auto generated class called SpecFlow.Plus.Runner.AssemblyHooks from SpecFlow (3.1.97).

This class is located in a .cs file at "obj" folder and I do not think it makes sense to keep having these warnings shown up.

I would say it would be nice to have these warning fixed by whoever generates the class.

Until then, how can I disable these warnings only for this specific file? I do not want to disable these warnings for the entire project.

Comment: You may have to add [EditorConfig](https://editorconfig.org/) file and then do `[*.MyGenerated.cs]' generated_code = true` for your file and then suppress violation `dotnet_diagnostic.CA1822.severity = none` as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/use-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2019#set-rule-severity-from-solution-explorer)

Comment: No sure what "generated_code = true" means in that case, but I could make it work. Thanks.

Comment: Glad , you got that working. I will add my comment as an answer. You can upvote/accept , if you think it helped you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to add EditorConfig file and then do `[*.MyGenerated.cs]' generated_code = true` for your file and then suppress violation `dotnet_diagnostic.CA1822.severity = none` as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/use-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2019#set-rule-severity-from-solution-explorer)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @user1207289, I managed to make it work.

By setting the severity level of the affected warning, a .editorconfig file is added to the solution. What I did is to make it like this:

```
[*.AssemblyHooks.cs]

# CA1707: Identifiers should not contain underscores
dotnet_diagnostic.CA1707.severity = silent

# CA1052: Static holder types should be Static or NotInheritable
dotnet_diagnostic.CA1052.severity = silent
```

And then warning were gone.